# Use XOR to encode and decode a message

Tags: java, ascii, xor

I'm using a XOR to encode and decode a message:

```
class Search {
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    String msg = "This is a test";
    String encmsg = "";
    String decmsg = "";
    int key = 88;
    
    System.out.print("Original message: ");
    System.out.println(msg);
    
    // encode the message.
    for(int i=0; i < msg.length(); i++)
        encmsg = encmsg + (char) (msg.charAt(i) ^ key);
    
    System.out.print("Encoded message: ");
    System.out.println(encmsg);
    
    // Decode the message.
    for(int i=0; i < msg.length(); i++)
        decmsg = decmsg + (char) (encmsg.charAt(i) + key);
    
    System.out.print("Decoded message: ");
    System.out.println(decmsg);
    
    }
}
```

As you can see, the result of the two XORs using the same key should produce the decoded message.
The unary one's complement (NOT) operator reverses the state of all the bits of the operand. I'll leave you the output:

```
Original message: This is a test
Encoded message: 01+x1+x9x,=+,
Decoded message: dˆ‰ƒÐ‰ƒÐ‘Ð„•ƒ„
```

Expected output:

```
Original message: This is a test
Encoded message: 01+x1+x9x,=+,
Decoded message: This is a test
```

What's wrong? The problem may be connected to the ASCII

Answer (score 1):

There might be a typo in your decode code block,you just need to change

```
decmsg = decmsg + (char) (encmsg.charAt(i) + key);
```

to

```
decmsg = decmsg + (char) (encmsg.charAt(i) ^ key);
```

The output is listed as below:

```
Original message: This is a test
Encoded message: 01+x1+x9x,=+,
Decoded message: This is a test
```

BTW, we had better to use `{}` within the `if` code block to make our code more easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator should be replaced by `^` in your decoding.

Because you use [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator to encode. Therefore you should stick on this operator to decode.